# Significant Mann Kendall Tau

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to look at trends in vegetation (NDVI) in Northern Portugal. I have used the `ee.Reducer.kendallsCorrelation` to calculate the Tau, and it also outputs the associated p-value for each pixel. When I try to visualise the p-value image it adds an empty layer to the map. I have tried to find documentation on how to use  `ee.Reducer.kendallsCorrelation` and specifically the the p-value layer, but haven't found anything.

Is there an easy way to visualise the p-value of the Mann Kendall Tau and find pixels with a significant Tau?

This is the code I have used

```
var sigTau = taus.select("ndvi_p-value").clip(roi); 

var visParams_tausig = {
  min: 0, 
  max: 1, 
  palette: ["white", "black"]
}

// var palette = ["black", "white"]; 

Map.addLayer(sigTau, visParams_tausig, "Tau Significant");
```